# Android fragment not created after runtime

Tags: android, user-interface, fragment

I'm trying to add a fragment to an activity after the content view in the activity has been set. I'm not using the compatibility package and have my target API set to 16. I'm expecting the activity to be set to the fragments layout after the setContentView method in the main activity but on runtime, the fragment is never added and the screen in blank. The callbacks for the life cycle events in the fragment are never called thus the System.outs don't output. Logcat doesn't output any errors relating to fragments either. If a fragment element is made in the activity_main.xml, the fragment works fine but adding it to the RelativeLayout in the class doesn't work. Can someone please help me? Thanks!
Edit: Tried using a FrameLayout as the fragment_container but no difference.

This is my main activity:

```
package com.example.derp;  

import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.app.Fragment;  
import android.app.FragmentManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Fragment frag = new Fragment();
    FragmentManager fManager = getFragmentManager();
    fManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, frag).commit();
}
}
```

This is my fragment:

```
 package com.example.derp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Frag extends Fragment{

public Frag(){

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    System.out.println("onAttach");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("onCreate");
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    System.out.println("onStart");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    System.out.println("onCreateView");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag, container, false);//
}
}
```

This is the fragment_frag.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >    

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating the instance of your fragment class. Rather you are creating the base fragment class's object.

Change...

```
Fragment frag = new Fragment();
```

To...

```
Fragment frag = new Frag();
```

Comment: Dude, your my hero. Such a simple fix, you have my gratitude.